# Creating SVG download link by php POST data

Tags: php, svg

This code can work fine.

```
<?php
$file = "forumsmap.svg";
header('Content-type: image/svg+xml');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
echo('<svg width="362" height="256" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><!-- Created with SVG-edit - https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit--><g><title>Layer 1</title><ellipse ry="23" rx="75" id="svg_7" cy="123" cx="191.5" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="null" stroke="#000000" fill="#ffffff"/></g></svg>');
?>
```

but when I modify the code by using POST data

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['content'];
$file = "forumsmap.svg";
header('Content-type: image/svg+xml');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
echo $data;
?>
```

And I open the SVG file I got this error message:

This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Plz tell me how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: Likely an issue with character encoding. Please include the results of `print_r($data);`

Comment: I try to use the GET method, and it can work fine. It's seem like something wrong with POST method?

Comment: I solve it by using grab the svg data by .html() function and using the POST method by form , thx for help

Comment: What's going on, is probably the extra newlines in POST (which is supposed to seperate variables by newlines AND `&`.  GET is intended for the querystring (url), so never includes newlines.  The POST also often includes additional information that you DON'T want to include in the response. echo the POST `$data` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: `echo "XXX". $data ."XXX";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Take a much closer look at the `$data` variable. It likely contains a newline at the end, which is invalid for the content-type you specified.

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['content'];
$file = "forumsmap.svg";
header('Content-type: image/svg+xml');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
echo $data;
print_r($data);
```

That should give you a better idea of what is going on.

## Server Errors, or other components modifying content.

Ultimately, there are a large variety of potential causes to the issue you are describing, anything from a Server-Error dumping HTML content into the `$_POST['content']` variable, to the that data not being properly encoded for `image/svg+xml`